# How to get a theano function to return the an array of the same length as another tensor variable

Tags: theano

I am really new to Theano, and I am just trying to figure out some basic functionality. I have a tensor variable x, and i would like the functio to return a tensor variable y of the same shape, but filled with value 0.2. I am not sure how to define y.

For example if x = [1,2,3,4,5], then I would like y = [0,2, 0,2, 0,2, 0,2, 0.2]

```
from theano import tensor, function
y = tensor.dmatrix('y')

masked_array = function([x],y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a dozen different ways to do this and which is best will depend on the context: how this piece of code/functionality fits into the wider program.

Here's one approach:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt

x = tt.vector()
y = tt.ones_like(x) * 0.2
f = theano.function([x], outputs=y)
print f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```